# hadoop.temp.files not getting generated

Tags: hadoop

I am a newbie to hadoop using hadoop in a single server node, i have setup the hadoop environment and have set my core-site.XML file in  the conf folder of Hadoop as

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/home/oracle/Hadoop/hadoop_temp_files</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

After setting the respected configuration I formatted the namenode and started the agents.

All the agents started as expected but no dir. with hadoop_temp_files got created. inside Hadoop, What could be the possible problem.

```
I am logged in to a server remotely, 
The usergroup oracle to which I am remotely logged into, however is not added to the sudoers and doesn't have admin right. Can this be the reason of the hadoop_temp_files dir not getting created.
Also when I started the agents all the agents started, but while stopping the agents by writting stop-all.sh the output responded:
There's no tasktracker to stop   and
there's no secondarynode to stop
```

Please help me clarify my problem.

Comment: Go through all the exceptions which is coming on start and post here.. Upload some files to your hdfs to find out if some problem exists..

Comment: There's no Exception, Its just In my local machine when as soon as started the agents (namenode), jobtracker, task tracker etc for the first time the temp file hadoop_temp_file got generated , but when I followed the same procedure in a server installation the dir hadoop_temp_files didnt get generated.